# Changing robot initial pose in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, pose, srdf, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to modify the initial pose by changing pr2.sdrf (pr2_description/robots). after rerun: roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch, the robot pose remains the same as the original one.
I have no idea where to look for make the proper changes. Any idea would be appreciated. Running on fuerte 12.04 ubuntu precise.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64368/changing-robot-initial-pose-in-gazebo/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [pr2_no_controllers.launch](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/stacks/pr2_simulator/trunk/pr2_gazebo/pr2_no_controllers.launch?rev=36301) they make use of "optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE". So, setting that env variable should change the location. Or you could modify the pose used with the spawn command in your own launch files.

Looks like a duplicate ..
[how-do-i-set-the-inital-pose-of-a-robot-in-gazebo](http://answers.ros.org/question/40627/how-do-i-set-the-inital-pose-of-a-robot-in-gazebo/)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-06-06**:
I have a look to the that post, but when I try to execute move_arm_joint_goal, errors stating that kinematic has experienced conflict with the initial pose. Do you know what packages that I need to modify (to generate) so I can build my own? Thanks